# Adding a class with multiple links in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding an background image for third party links with filter function like this

```
$("a").filter(function () {
                var ignoreLink =
        this.hostname == location.hostname // disregard same domain
        || this.href.match(/^(mailto|tel|javascript)\:/)
                return !ignoreLink;
            }).addClass("externalanchor").attr("target", "_blank");
```

the above  code works fine now i have a requirement saying that some of the links  should be internal ex:

```
<p><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Email URL</a></p>
<p><a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">Google</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Google</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.codecademy.com" target="_blank">Google</a></p>
```

my question is  How to add a class for this links separate with out a dom change only with jquery.

Comment: Do you want add a class to elements which have target blank? or do you want add target blank and a class to elements with external websites? ive did the both ways, tell me what do you want

Comment: $("a[href="https://www.google.com/"],
      [href="https://github.com/"],
      [href="https://www.w3schools.com"],
      [href="https://www.codecademy.com"]").addClass("no-external");
   });   i need some thing like this

Comment: Like `$('a[href^="http"').addClass('no-external')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("a[href*='google.com'], a[href*='w3schools.com'], a[href*='codeacademy.com']").addClass('no-external');
```

Comment: @susanth there is an error if i use double quotes inside  $("a[href*="w3schools.com"], a[href*="codeacademy.com"], a[href*="google.com"]").addClass("no-external");Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Qb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: If you want to use double quotes, you will have to escape them, otherwise it would result in unterminated string. It is better to use a combination of double and single quotes, which is lot more cleaner. `$("a[href*=\"w3schools.com\"], a[href*=\"codeacademy.com\"], a[href*=\"google.com\"]")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this works for you?:

https://jsfiddle.net/khkmmjjn/1/

Code:

```
$("a").each(function(){

  if( $(this).attr("href").indexOf("https://jsfiddle.net") == 0 || 
     $(this).attr("href").indexOf("jsfiddle.net") == 0 )
  {
    $(this).addClass("local");
  }
  else if( $(this).attr("href").indexOf("mailto:") == 0 || 
     $(this).attr("href").indexOf("tel:") == 0 )
  {
    $(this).addClass("other");
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).addClass("external");
  }

});
```